# React-native with Expo: How to make Expo auth-session redirect to same instance of app instead of opening new instance seperately?

Tags: javascript, react-native, oauth, expo

I have tried making the absolute simplest possible spotify authentication application, that follows the first part of the [authorization code flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow).
I use the [auth.expo.io](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/auth-session/#what--authexpoio--does-for-you) proxy for redirection.
The code is based on [the official expo documentation](https://docs.expo.io/guides/authentication/#spotify).

It looks like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import { makeRedirectUri, useAuthRequest } from 'expo-auth-session';
import { Button } from 'react-native';

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

// Endpoint
const discovery = {
  authorizationEndpoint: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize',
  tokenEndpoint: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
};

export default function App() {
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
    {
      clientId: 'b5b960a874e54e7996741fcc3ca59684',
      scopes: ['user-read-email', 'playlist-modify-public'],
      usePKCE: false,
      redirectUri: makeRedirectUri({ useProxy: true }),
    },
    discovery
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (response?.type === 'success') {
      const { code } = response.params;
      console.log(code)
    }

  }, [response]);

  return (
    <Button
      disabled={!request}
      title="Login"
      onPress={() => {
        promptAsync({ useProxy: true });
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

But when getting redirected, instead of returning to the open version of the app, a new "copy" of the app is opened, as visible on the below picture.

[image]

This, of course, makes the useEffect not trigger, rendering me unable to obtain the code.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Hi Joachim, Did you got the solution to this. If so can you please post the complete answer please.

Comment: I actually ended up scrapping the idea, unfortunately, and ran React Native without Expo.
This was too bad, as I had done a lot of work on my app, but luckily much of the code could be reused. Using OAuth worked perfectly without using Expo. Best of luck.